# How to package lib.so files into a .whl file so user don't have to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a `mypackage` wheel `mypackage-py3.7-linux-x86_64` that installs into `/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypackage-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg` and adds dependencies:

```
/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libdependencyroot.so
/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libdependencydeeper.so
```

My $LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to contain everything one would ever need:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>>> /usr/local/conda/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

And than when I try to use

```
python
import mypackage
...
>>> ImportError: libdependencyroot.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I copy lib files under `/usr/local/conda/lib` or add `/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` to LD_LIBRARY_PATH the problem disappears.

Let's say I can go and redesign the `mypackage-py3.7-linux-x86_64.whl`. What should I do there to make my dependencies discoverable? I don't want to mess with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I am not sure if it is a fair game for a whl to put things under `/usr/local/conda/lib`.

Comment: I think this need clarification, or at least a retagging. What is the actual install mechanism? Pip or Conda? If the former, then add `pip` tag; if the latter, then add a `conda-build` tag. Right now the `conda` tag kinda seems out of place.

Comment: So what's actually on the `sys.path`?  Everything in site-packages should usually be findable.

Comment: That sort of thing `['',
'/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
'/usr/local/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypackage-0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg']` So, technically `usr/local/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages` where the dependencies are is already under the path. It might be because one lib.so depends on another lib.so and path is not involved there. But it is a wild guess

Comment: looks like your package installed to python3.7's site but you're using python3.8 .

Comment: Sorry, must have copied from the wrong env. It is the same python